# `cannot read property ‘setDirtyAttribute’ of null` even if you use `YourModel.create({…})` in `ember-typescript-cli`

Tags: javascript, typescript, ember.js, ember-data

Facing `cannot read property 'setDirtyAttribute' of null` even if you use `YourModel.create({...})` in `ember-typescript-cli`to create a EmberObject.

Model:

```js
import DS from 'ember-data';
import {computed} from "@ember/object";

export default class Person extends DS.Model {
  @DS.attr() firstName!: string;
  @DS.attr() lastName!: string;
  @DS.attr() age!: number;
  @DS.attr() desc?: string;


  @computed("firstName", "lastName")
  public get fullName() {
    return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
  }
}
```

Route:

```js
export default class Persons extends Route {
  @service() public store!: DS.Store;

  constructor() {
    super(...arguments);

    const persons: Person[] = [
      Person.create({firstName: "first1", lastName: "last1", age: 10}),
      Person.create({firstName: "first2", lastName: "last2", age: 320}),
      Person.create({firstName: "first3", lastName: "last3", age: 30}),
    ];
      persons.forEach(p => this.store.createRecord('person', p));
  }
}
```

Get error when enter the page:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setDirtyAttribute' of null
    at Person.set (-private.js:144)
    at ComputedProperty._set (metal.js:3543)
    at ComputedProperty.setWithSuspend (metal.js:3532)
    at ComputedProperty.set (metal.js:3503)
    at initialize (core_object.js:67)
    at Function.create (core_object.js:692)
    at new Persons (persons.js:23)
    at Function.create (core_object.js:684)
    at FactoryManager.create (container.js:549)
    at instantiateFactory (container.js:359)
```

So I have to use things like `this.store.createRecord('person', {firstName: "first1", lastName: "last1", age: 10})` rather than  `this.store.createRecord('person', <a Person class instance>)`, which is not typescript-ish at all. So I hope to find a more elegant way to combine the ember feature to typescript, rather than use `any` or bare `object` everywhere.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation of Ember Data is quite clear that you shouldn't use `Model.create({})`. It's not only private API but even documented that instances of models should only be created using the store service:

> Create should only ever be called by the store. To create an instance
>   of a Model in a dirty state use store.createRecord.
>
> To create instances of Model in a clean state, use store.push
>
> https://api.emberjs.com/ember-data/3.11/classes/Model/methods/create?anchor=create&show=inherited%2Cprotected%2Cprivate

Ember Data's public APIs should work well with Typescript by default. The [known and documented bug](https://blog.emberjs.com/2019/07/15/ember-3-11-released.html) in `ember-data@3.11.0` should have been fixed in a later point release.

Please refer to [Ember CLI TypeScript's documentation about Ember Data support](https://typed-ember.github.io/ember-cli-typescript/docs/ts-guide/using-ts-effectively#ember-data-lookups) for supported setup.

Comment: I have read the doc before but still cannot find a better way to use grammar like `new Person(...)` or so to create a `Model` and be able to put it to `this.store.createRecord('person', <something>)`. I have tried `this.store.createRecord('person', {...new Person(...)})` or `this.store.createRecord('person', {...Person.create({...})})`. And I don't think the JS style is suitable in TS, which I think is not type-safe. Using bare object is not type-safe, you know.

Comment: You are trying something that is explicitly stated as not being supported in the docs. So you shouldn't complain if you face issues. There is established documentation about how to use Ember Data with Typescript. Major companies are using that setup in enterprise applications. So I'm quite sure it's the best solution for your problem. You shouldn't try to fight the framework you are using. That's a battle you can't win. If you like to change the behavior, you must go through the RFC process.

Comment: There is an [open feature request](https://github.com/typed-ember/ember-cli-typescript/issues/251) for type-checking input properties to `store.createRecord()`. It includes an idea how that improvement could be implemented. Maybe you want to give it a try and provide a PR? You would still pass a POJO but it's properties would be type checked.

Comment: Why is there a `create` method then if it's not supposed to be used? It's just bad design.

Comment: The `create` method exists for historical reasons. Ember Data's `Model` class extends `EmberObject`. `EmberObject` provided a class-like interface for building Ember applications long before native ECMAScript classes.